# iOS 8 beta 5 Game Center Sandbox won't recognize my app

Tags: ios, sandbox, ios8

I trying use GC sandbox in game, on iOS 7 it works fine, but on iOS 8 beta5  GC authentication return error "The requested operation could not be completed because this application is not recognized by Game Center". In production GC work fine on iOS 7 and 8 beta5.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should turn on the GC sandbox mode.

go to settings --> game center

scroll to the bottom, there is a "sandbox" swith under "developer".

(Important! - These developer options are hidden until you have connected the device to XCode 6. If you didn't use XCode and deployed your app in some other way - e.g. Testflight, iPCU, iTunes, then you will not see these options)

Comment: so wait, no sandbox for TestFlight testers?

Comment: I repeat, so wait, no sandbox for TestFlight testers?

Comment: Seems that way. Major cock up by someone at Apple if there really is no other way to enable this. As soon as a device has an ad-hoc app installed it should enable the settings at least. Or, just work it out and choose which Game Center mode to use based on the app?

Comment: Yes, this means we cant send out to testflight users unless they are developers. Major **** up!

Comment: The answer given by Andy Korth gives an alternative: Run the free TestFlight iOS app. (I realize this app probably did not exist when the other comments to this answer were written.) Not ideal to make testers do this if you are not otherwise using TestFlight, but still a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't seeing the sandbox switch under Settings > game center (developer section), then you need to connect the device to XCode

OR:
Use Apple's testflight iOS app found here on the App Store:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/testflight/id899247664?mt=8

That will enable the developer Sandbox switch as well. Using the old testflight web link tool on iOS doesn't enable the sandbox switch.

Comment: @Tyler A: Yes, it seems to work for me with an ad hoc install.

Comment: Oops, re-reading this, I realize I wasn't specific enough: Does the testflight solution work with ad hoc provisioning? i.e. will Sandbox show up for the test user who isn't testing any other applications and installed the app via sneakernet instead of through iTunes connect?

Answer (score 0):

If you plug in the device and then look at the settings/ gamecenter. The setting for the sandbox will show up.

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue and solved it by adding a leaderboard in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add an app to iTunes Connect and enable Game Center for it, not just the provisioning/entitlements. Then I added a leaderboard as Alcides Eduardo Zelaya [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37337425/168594).

From the [GKLocalPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gklocalplayer/1515399-authenticatehandler?language=objc) docs:

> Receiving a GKErrorGameUnrecognized error means that you have not enabled Game Center for your app in App Store Connect. Sign in to your App Store Connect account and verify that your app has Game Center enabled. Also, confirm that the bundle identifier in your Xcode project matches the bundle identifier you assigned to your app in App Store Connect.