# UnityEngine.Social not working with IOS 8. Unsure how to resolve the issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, ios8, game-center, xcode6

When running our game on any device that uses game center we get an error that is related to specifically the authentication/connection from the game to Game Center. Now this works on IOS 7 versions, just not with IOS 8.

We get this return from the authentication attempt,

Failed to authenticate local user The requested operation could not be completed because this application is not recognized by Game Centre.

Has anyone encountered this issue/problem? is this a unity related issue, or something from xCode and/or Apple and Game Centre?

Built from xCode v6.0.1, to IOS 8.

Comment: I'm having same issue as well

Comment: here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238646/ios-8-beta-5-game-center-sandbox-wont-recognize-my-app