# Unable to sign in to Game Center sandbox - GKErrorDomain Code=15

Tags: game-center

I can't sign in to sandbox game-center on iOS 8. Just keep on getting error, and no view controller in the response to authenticateHandler. Error is GKErrorDomain, and code is 15.

Comment: This is highly related and explains it. Things changed in iOS8 - you have to explicitly enable sandbox for GameCenter in iOS 8 - Settings app, Game Center, scroll to bottom. There should be a Sandbox switch there. If not, you have to connect the device to Xcode 6.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25541870/129202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reporting @jonny's comment, you have explicity enable sandbox for GameCenter in iOS8 - Settings app, Game Center, scroll to bottom.

Comment: I connected my device to Xcode 7 and ios 9, but not sandbox option under Developer.  What gives?

Comment: This was true until iOS8. On iOS9 the sandbox mode is "gone". One of the WWDC 2015 speeches goes through the details about that.