# iOS8: Impossible for Beta Testers to Access Game Center

Tags: ios, game-center

Many people are reporting that `Sandbox` mode is disabled by default on iOS8. This causes games built with an AdHoc profile (thus in Sandbox mode) to not be recognized by GameCenter, resulting in a GameCenter error:

- [iOS 8 beta 5 Game Center Sandbox wont recognize my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238646/ios-8-beta-5-game-center-sandbox-wont-recognize-my-app)

The problem is fixed by enabling `Sandbox` mode in the iOS8 device's settings, but AFAIK this can only de done by Developers (i.e., phone in developer mode), which requires XCode. But I need my game's beta testers to be able to use my game! Right now, they can't enable sandbox mode, and thus cannot connect to GameCenter.

Is there a way to make Ad-Hoc (Beta) builds NOT use Sandbox, or allow normal users (non developers) to turn on GameCenter Sandbox mode?

---

*edit*
It looks like this is an issue other devs are running into, and I can't find anybody who has found a solution yet. It is, essentially, impossible for beta testers to test a game due to this problem.
Blog post from another dev:
http://fliperamma.com/ios-8-game-center-sandbox-and-testflight/

Comment: This looks to me like a blatant mistake by Apple so far. An extremely frustrating one at that.

Answer (score 1):

If your testers install this version of TestFlight:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/testflight/id899247664?mt=8

Then it enables the switch for Sandbox mode in Settings.

Answer (score -1):

There is an option in the Game Centre Settings section.  In the developers section at the bottom of the game centre settings and you can enable sandbox mode.

Comment: Only if you're a developer, as I explained in the OP. And that's the problem. BETA testers are NOT developers.

Answer (score -1):

There is now a specific app for test flight testers using iOS8

please see [here](http://www.imore.com/testflight-ios-8-explained) and [here](http://www.imore.com/apple-releases-testflight-beta-testing-app) for further information.

Comment: TestFlight is NOT open to BETA testers yet. Only internal team members. This doesn't address the question at all, besides. I asked about AD-Hoc BETA builds.